# jQuery generates wrong html string '=" instead of just "

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm programming a web page for math tasks and want to set up a button which is generated dynamically, but my code generates '=" instead of " on the html page.

```
function generateButton(id){
    var b = "<button onclick='copyToClipboard(" + id + ", 'de');'>Copy to Clipboard </button>";
    $('#knopfdiv').append(b);
}
```

HTML

```
<div>
    <button onclick='generateButton(1);'>Show Button</button>
</div>
<div id="knopfdiv"></div>
```

So I expect the html line

```
<button onclick='copyToClipboard(1, 'de');'>Copy to Clipboard </button>
```

but I get

```
<button onclick="copyToClipboard(1, " de');'="">Copy to Clipboard </button>
```

and so that button does not work. What's wrong here?

Comment: You have single quotes nested within single quotes. That is not valid syntax. You could replace with escaped double quotes `\"de\"`

Comment: @melancia because both `'` and its nested `'` are inside `"`, there will not be a syntax error as it's a single string.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the variable (replace with hardcoded value), and take the HTML by itself, you get:

```
<button onclick='copyToClipboard(1, 'de');'>
```

It might not be obvious, but this has `onclick='..'de'..'` - ie a nested single quote within a single quote.  jQuery is attempting to interpret this for you.

As your HTML is already wrapped in `"`, you can't just replace with `, "de"` but you can escape the `"` to `\"`, giving:

```
<button onclick='copyToClipboard(1, \"de\");'>
```

applied to the javascript:

```
var b = "<button onclick='copyToClipboard(" + id + ", \"de\");'>Copy to Clipboard </button>";
```